# Configure NGINX to serve SPA application

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I'm very beginner in Nginx, so I follow an online guide to configure it to serve my React web application. Obviously, in debug mode my application works like a charm.

My test_server:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/my-app/build;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }}
```

After deploy when i try to enter a different path (e.g.: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/home) it always responde 404. How to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some redirect rules.

Have a look at my setup:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/$1 redirect;
  if ($http_host ~* "^rickvanlieshout.com"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.rickvanlieshout.com/$1 redirect;
  }
  if ($http_host ~* "^mastermindzh.com"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.mastermindzh.com/$1 redirect;
  }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
  }
}
```

You can also do it with .htaccess if your server supports it:

```
# Enable rewriting.
RewriteEngine on
# Optional: do not allow perusal of directories.
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rickvanlieshout.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rickvanlieshout.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mastermindzh.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mastermindzh.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Optional: explicitly enable per-directory rewrites in the .htaccess context.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# To be able to access existing directories and files (standalone scripts).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Redirect everything else to index.html.
# Add QSA to ensure that querystring variables are registered as such.
RewriteRule . index.html [L,QSA]
```